# Modify Source Observable on retry - RxJava

Tags: rx-java

How do i update a source observable on retry?

```
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>(); // A,B,C
Observable.from(ids)
          .retryWhen(errors -> {
                    return errors
                    .zipWith(Observable.range(0, 1), (n, i) -> i)
                    .flatMap(retryCount -> Observable.timer((long) Math.pow(2, retryCount), TimeUnit.MINUTES));

           })
           .subscribe(....);
```

now rather than passing //A,B,C as ids if i want to pass some other values. How do i do it? or is this even the right approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `defer`. This would allow `ids` to be re-computed:

```
Observable.defer(() -> {
    List<String> ids = // compute this somehow
    return Observable.from(ids);
}).retryWhen(...
```

[Documentation on the defer operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/defer.html)

Comment: i just have a one subscriber. defer creates a fresh observable for each observer. don't you think onErrorResumeNext is a better option?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean?  The subscription callback itself is the observer - it receives the incoming items from upstream. Hence the term "observABLE" for the thing you are observing - it's producing items which may be observed by an observer.  Multiple observers might imply that you're multicasting, which in this example you're not.

Answer (score 1):

`onErrorResumeNext` could be used. You probably need some additional logic to match your use case. Documentation for error handling operators [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators).

```
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>(); // A,B,C
List<String> ids2 = new ArrayList<>(); // D,E,F
Observable.from(ids)
        .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
            return Observable.from(ids2);
        });
```

Comment: onErrorResumeNext is called when retryWhen timer elapses?

Comment: Well currently it would be called straight after the error is emitted from the first observable, you would have to add the timer logic yourself.

Comment: i already have a timer logic in retryWhen. But, i assume the timer logic should as part of the onErrorResumeNext?

Comment: Yeah, the timer logic would have to go in `onErrorResumeNext` in this case.